# How to center banner with jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am building a jquery mobile site , and i would like the banner of my company to be positioned like [stanford's](http://m.standford.edu) mobile site , which in a mobile device looks like this :

[image]

The size of this image is 320x280 , that means that it perfect fits the screen of phones with width of 320 (like the iphone i am using in this case). In the rest of the phones with bigger screens , it will leave a gap left and right and still look awesome.

I tried to replicate this behavior for my site. However the result looks far from that. I used the exact same picture from the stanford site , so that i am sure there is not a dimension problem. My site looks like that:

[image]

As you can see there is a gap in the upper and left side, that i cant understand why is there.

Diving a bit more in stanfords mobile website , i find the css that they are using for the banner :

```
/* Home page banner */
h2#banner {
    background:transparent url(../img/banner/banner.jpg) no-repeat left 10px;
    width:320px;
    height:284px;
    margin:-10px auto -150px auto;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}
/* Home page banner landscape */
.landscape h2#banner {
    background:transparent url(../img/banner/banner-landscape.jpg) no-repeat left 10px;
    width:480px;
    height:290px;
    margin:-10px auto -175px auto;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}
/* Remove reduntant extra top padding - don't put h2's in front of ul.listview */
h2 {
    margin:0;
    font-size:20px;
}
```

I used the exact same code but still i have the issue.

Any ideas what is going on here with the CSS and how i can center it exactly?

### ----

---

I also tried my site in a phone with a bigger screen. There the banner is centered with a gap up left and right. Again though , there should be a gap only left and right and not up.

### EDIT

---

After combining the solutions suggested i ended up with something like that :

```
h2#banner {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background:transparent url(images/banner.png) no-repeat left 10px;
    width:320px;
    height:284px;
    margin:-10px auto -150px auto;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}
```

which results to :

[image]

I cant though, move the image upper so more banner is visible. With the previous solution i just had to change the height attribute and more space was reveiled/covered. I really think the solution is inside the stanfords webpage. I cant find it cause my understanding of this , is not mature yet. But the css is really small , should be obvious what they are doing. I like the way they override the title with an image and that the image works separately from the rest of the content.

Comment: Add background image to `ui-content`.

Comment: You mean in the html? It is inside the content.

Comment: No CSS `ui-content { background-image: img.png !important }` something like this. I'm outside the office I can't give you a definite answer.

Comment: I did but not significant difference. Actually in stanfords website they have: /* Remove background seal */
.ui-content {
 background:none;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/MgSP7/

**HTML :**

```
<div data-role="content">
    <h2 id="banner"></h2>
    <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b" data-inset="true" id="custom-list">
        <li><a href="item1.html">item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="item1.html">item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="item1.html">item1</a></li>
    </ul>                
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
#banner {
    position: absolute;
    top:43px;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    padding: 0 !important;
    background:transparent url('http://m.stanford.edu/img/banner/banner.jpg') no-repeat center top !important;
}

#custom-list {
    margin-top: 150px;    
}
```

Comment: Yes it could work , but this will make all my content have no gaps in the left and right , that i wouldnt like. If you the screenshots i need the main menu to have gaps left and right. Also i dont want to reposition all the ui-content but the banner. My content is positioned exactly as i like it. If possible look the source code from the stanford page , maybe you get an idea how they do it as you are much more experienced.

Comment: again the problem is that you are tweaking the ui-content. This streches all the content. I think the solution lies here : h2#banner {
    background:transparent url(../img/banner/banner.jpg) no-repeat left 10px;
    width:320px;
    height:284px;
    margin:-10px auto -150px auto;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}
We have to tweak the h2 banner only.

Comment: Well still it had minor problems when i tried to implement it. See my edited question to see what i did in the end , but still there is a problem

Comment: Sorry but your comment is confusing. Why would you move image upper that doesn't make any sense. You need to move listview down, this will show you more of a banner. Is this what you want?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/MgSP7/ Then all you need to do is set margin-top to listview. Give it some id or class like in my example and set margin-top to any value that satisfies you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any image size.

See DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/DHUup/2/ with background image size of 1600x1200 px.

Tips : cover gradient color on bottom of your image to match with your background color.

## HTML

```
<div id="myBanner" data-role="page">

    <!--<div data-role="header">
        <h1>Stanford</h1>
    </div> /header -->

    <div data-role="content" style="margin-top:200px;">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cadillac</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ferrari</a></li>
        </ul>
    <div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->
```

## This CSS will do it all for you, both potrait & landscape.

```
#myBanner{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:url(http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/the_glorious_church_at_stanford-normal.jpg);
    background-size:100% auto;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Actually is not a background image. Is a title <h2> .... </h2> , that i override with a banner. So in case something goes wrong with the banner i have the title. Could you help me exactly with this case , rather than showing me how to use an image as background?

Comment: i will play around with your <h2> tag and let you know.

Comment: thanks a lot yeyene. really appreciate your effort. If your understanding on this, is mature , try to see the stanford source code. Is really small and should be obvious how they do it.

Comment: before my code, update your css background...
from / background:transparent url(../img/banner/banner.jpg) no-repeat left 10px; /
to /background:transparent url(../img/banner/banner.jpg) no-repeat top center; /

Comment: I did but in the phone doesnt look good.. It still shows with gap up and left

Comment: humm, let me see your main content div, I suspect there is some margin or padding. Let me see your html and css.